# How to use Heroku worker process for a Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, heroku

I am building a Spring boot application. I have exposed an API which will be invoked from the Angular client. The controller will be responsible to invoke a task which uses @Async annotation.

Currently I am running a web app only on Heroku. Do I need to create a separate worker app to process the asynchronous task? If yes, please suggest what changes in the application is required for the same.